# ColdFusion 8 connect to remote access MDB

Tags: database, ms-access, coldfusion

I have an Access MDB file on a different server than my ColdFusion server, is there any way I can get ColdFusion 8 to be able to connect to it over the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need file access to the other server.  You can then connect to the database in the usual way.  Or you can make a copy of the database and transfer it over the network to your ColdFusion server.

Jet MDB's are file accessed based.  You can't run them as a database server AFAIK.  To do that you would need to upsize the database to an actual database server like SQL Server Express, and connect to that in the usual way.

If you have IIS running on the remote server, you can try this hack:

```
Dim strSQL As String
 'assign connection string
strConString = "Provider=MS Remote;" & _
               "Remote Server=http://192.168.1.1;" & _
               "Remote Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data Source=MyRemoteDB;Persist Security Info=False"
    'initialize connection object variable
Set adoConn = New ADODB.Connection
'open connection adoConn.Open strConString, "admin", ""
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above idea, you could create a secured VPN connection to the server via a firewall or using microsoft's vpn.  Then map a drive letter and use it like normal.

Other .NET trickery that would do the trick but I think one of the two ideas would be easiest..

Do you have to run off a live copy of the database?