# connect remote MS Access DB using PHP

Tags: php, database, ms-access, database-connection

I have my site running on one server(PHP) say site-1 and there is other site which is running on other server say site-2.

So i need to connect to MS Access DB located on site-2 from site-1.

how can I do that?

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214826/coldfusion-8-connect-to-remote-access-mdb

Comment: With that is the possible to connect remote MSaccess from linux to Apache?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you won't do it without extra libraries. Access is a file-based database. There's no "server" to connect to. And Microsoft is NOT going to be providing a Linux/Unix-based connection library to let you actually talk to that .mdb file, so you'll have to go 3rd party, which probably means $$$.

And in any case, while Access is ok for low-volume light-traffic duty, you most likely do not want to use it for any reasonably large site (say, 5 or more concurrent users). It's not intended for that kind of duty. If the data store size isn't too big, you can upgrade to SQL Server Express, which is basically a fully functional SQL Server, but limited to 10gig (I think, going off pre-coffee memory) total data size.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 bumped the MDF file size to 10GBs. Previous to that, the limitation was 4GBs, which was twice the max for MDB/ACCDB.